# Converting data to Excel from Matlab

Tags: excel, matlab

In matlab one of my variable produce a sort of number as follows:
t =

1.0e-07 *

Columns 1 through 4

0.000002188044002   0.000011853757224   0.000043123777130   0.000134856642090

Columns 5 through 8

0.000414700915105   0.001479279377534   0.003134050793671   0.008617995925603

Columns 9 through 12

0.065830078792745   0.087987267599604   0.106338163623915   0.121617374878836

Columns 13 through 16

0.134520178924611   0.145518794399287   0.155035638788571   0.163042823513867

Columns 17 through 18

0.170181805020581   0.172442168463983

How I can produce them in one column in order to easily copy and paste  to Excel?

Comment: if all you want to do is copy & paste may be easiest to do it from the variable editor (double click variable in the workspace window or with openvar varname) then copy and paste

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
format long g
t'
```

or else just double click on t in your workspace and you'll get a datagrid (the variable editor) that you can just copy and paste out of

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
fprintf ('%g\n', t);
```

Which won't have the leading spaces you get from `format long g; t'`